# Logic App - Copy from sharepoint to Azure BlobStorage

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am currently testing my newly created workflow. The goal is to copy the files from sharepoint to blobstorage.

It needs to check in certain intervals if something has been added or updated in sharepoint and then copy it.

For this I use **'When a file is created or modified (properties only)'**, followed by a couple of **'Initialize variable'** to adjust path etc. and after that comes **'Get file content'**. At the end **'Upload blob to storage container'**.

It works fine, however it only copies the files that have been added/updated to sharepoint after workflow was created.

My question is if it is possible to copy also the files that were already in sharepoint before creating workflow.

Thanks : ))

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this done by listing the files from required folder and creating the blob using `Get file content using path`. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I can't see the images, can you please update them?

Comment: @gio.s I have reuploaded them. Can you recheck from your end.

Comment: is there a way or a workaround to use 'Initialize Variable' in for each loop?

Comment: @gio.s You cannot Initialize variable inside loops instead you can set variables

Comment: It works what you said, but it was not useful for my case. I tried get files(properties only) to list all files in different folders. But it still doesn't work because files are nested deep in folders and the action gets to a certain depth. And it seems to be an known issue, I fount it somewhere on microsoft site.